# Problem with page numbering with pageslts

Tags: pageslts

I am trying to make a package that will input a subfile as an appendix. I would like to have the ordinary pages numbered with arabic numbers and the appendix numbered with roman numbers. I also have to show how many pages there are in the two parts. I have succeded in making the numbering, but when I try to include the appendix files I get the error message:

> pageslts Error: pagenumbering scheme missing.

Now I have read the manual without any help. May be one of you can direct me to a solution
Here is a my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vedlegg}{m}
{
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Side \, \thepage\ av \, \lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}
    \appendix

    \section*{My appendix}
    \input{#1}
}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Page \thepage\ of \theCurrentPageLocal}

    \lipsum[1]

    \vedlegg{appendix.tex}
\end{document}
```

The file appendix.tex should be any tex file.
Does the problem stem from including another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a page numbering scheme for the appendix (`\pagenumbering{roman}`) but you did not set any for the main document. Just add

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

(or whichever scheme you prefer) before `\begin{document}`.

Here is a working example. I compiled it with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vedlegg}{m}
{
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Side \, \thepage\ av \, \lastpageref{pagesLTS.roman}}
    \appendix

    \section*{My appendix}
    \input{#1}
}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Page \thepage\ of \theCurrentPageLocal}

    \lipsum[1]

    \vedlegg{appendix.tex}
\end{document}
```